# After installing virtualenv, I can no longer run ipython / jupyter

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, hashlib

I had been happily using ipython in Windows 7 for many months, but recently decided to play with django.  The guide I was looking at recommended installing virtualenv, which I did and that worked great (or so it seemed).

Now, however, when I try to launch ipython (or jupyter) I get the following error:

```
C:\Python\Scripts>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 60, in <module>
    from .services.contents.manager import ContentsManager
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\contents\manager.py", line 16, in <module>
    from nbformat import sign, validate, ValidationError
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\nbformat\sign.py", line 33, in <module>
    algorithms = hashlib.algorithms
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'algorithms'
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling jupyter, hashlib, and even python itself, with no success.  I'm using pip to do the installs, and I have setup-tools installed too.  I'm thinking about reformatting my hard drive and starting over, but that seems a bit extreme.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you upgrade from python2 to python3? `hashlib.algorithms` is removed in py3. What's the output of `python --version`?

Comment: C:\Python\Scripts>python --version
Python 2.7.11 :: Anaconda 2.4.0 (64-bit)

Comment: FWIW, I gave up and uninstalled everything, then reinstalled Anaconda.  Now all is well.  From here on I will consider virtualenv incompatible with Jupyter / iPython, although one thing I didn't try was installing and running Jupyter in a virtualenv... perhaps others will chime in if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing your final question in the comment, they have a nice section in their docs about using a virtualenv kernel as the backend for a jupyter notebook.

http://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/IPythonNotebookVirtualenvs

Copying from the docs in case the link goes dead:

You can use a virtualenv for your IPython notebook. Follow the following steps:

Install the ipython kernel module into your virtualenv

```
workon my-virtualenv-name  # activate your virtualenv, if you haven't already
pip install ipykernel
```

Now run the kernel "self-install" script:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=my-virtualenv-name
```

Replacing the --name parameter as appropriate.

You should now be able to see your kernel in the IPython notebook menu: Kernel -> Change kernel and be able so switch to it (you may need to refresh the page before it appears in the list). IPython will remember which kernel to use for that notebook from then on.

Comment: Thanks, ClimbsRocks!